# Url like shirt7 or shirtseven - interesting, does google understand written numbers

Tags: seo

Hi we are looking to find the best domain we can. We have a product where people always search for "shirt 7". the domain shirt7.com is taken, but instead we can claim "shirtseven.com"

When someone searches for "shirt 7", would google then rank "shirtseven.com" lower, higher or equal (all other elements the same)

or in other words, is it a good idea to claim "shirtseven.com"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No short answer for that. ;)

It will depend on the content, how heavy is the keyword shirt 7 on shirtseven.com, and on shirt7.com

An example for that is 7 up (the drink) both searches "7 up" and "seven up" give similar results but on a mixed order, that is because some of the sites have more emphasis on the phrase "7up" and others on the phrase "seven up".

You can claim shirtseven.com just you need to remember that users will or may use both ways to search for the site. If you are confident that the users allway search for your site by shirt 7 make sure you strongly use that keyword on your site.